# How to use wildcard in Apache Ant's to define property value

Tags: properties, ant, wildcard

I have a property tags where I need to define property value using wildcard
to use it for "11.0.11; 11.0.13; 11.0.16; etc..".

```
<property name="java.version" value="11.0.*" />
```

How to use wildcard to define property value?
Thank you.

Comment: A property can have only a single, fixed value.  If you need to match a set of resources you may be able to do so with a different task, depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?  Or can you add a bit more info so folks can suggest ideas?